# node js Get Zip From a URL and upload to Google drive

Tags: node.js, url, request, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the zip file from a url for uploading it in the next step to Google drive. But my code doesn't work.

```js
// The method to get the zip File from the url

function getFile(){

var file = request({
  method : "GET",
  url : "https://start.spring.io/starter.zip",
  encoding: null // <- this one is important !
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if(error ||  response.statusCode !== 200) {
    // handle error
    return;
  }
  JSZip.loadAsync(body).then(function (zip) {
    return zip.file("content.txt").async("string");
  }).then(function () {
    console.log(text);
  });
});
}

// method to upload zip to drive 

function uploadFile(auth) {
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
    var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'demo.zip'
    };
    var media = {
        mimeType: 'application/zip',
        body: fs.createReadStream(getFile())
    };
    drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        fields: 'id'
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            // Handle error
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('File Id: ', res.data.id);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to get the zip file from the url above, but it throws an Exception:

```
new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);
```

When I change the body: `fs.createReadStream(getFile())` to body: `fs.createReadStream("https://start.spring.io/starter.zip")`

```
the Exception is: no such file or directory, open 'https://start.spring.io/starter.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to download a zip file from URL and upload it to your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put the file using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Value retrieved from the URL by `request` can be used for uploading.
- The value retrieved from the URL is uploaded is buffer. So please convert it to the readstream type.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getFile() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(
      {
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://start.spring.io/starter.zip",
        encoding: null // <- this one is important !
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        if (error && response.statusCode != 200) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve(body);
      }
    );
  });
}

function uploadFile(auth) {
  const stream = require("stream"); // In this script, use this module.

  getFile().then(body => {
    const bs = new stream.PassThrough();
    bs.end(body);
    const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
    var fileMetadata = {
      name: "demo.zip"
    };
    var media = {
      mimeType: "application/zip",
      body: bs // Modified
    };
    drive.files.create(
      {
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        fields: "id"
      },
      function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("File Id: ", res.data.id);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

#### Other pattern:

Of course, `uploadFile()` can be also modified as follows.

```
async function uploadFile(auth) {
  const stream = require("stream"); // In this script, use this module.

  const buffer = await getFile();
  const bs = new stream.PassThrough();
  bs.end(buffer);

  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
  var fileMetadata = {
    name: "demo.zip"
  };
  var media = {
    mimeType: "application/zip",
    body: bs // Modified
  };
  drive.files.create(
    {
      resource: fileMetadata,
      media: media,
      fields: "id"
    },
    function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("File Id: ", res.data.id);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

#### References:

- [Class: stream.PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough)
- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/drive)
- [Files: create of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

In my environment, I could confirm that this modified script worked. But if I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much for your detailed response !

Comment: @Klaus Kledan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.